# Explaining complicated grammar

Tags: grammaticality-in-context

I'm wondering if you could teach me a grammatical understanding of the following sentence:

> If you give Benjamin Netanyahu that recognition without him having to give the Palestinians anything, which is what he wants, you've cut the Palestinians off at the knees.

Comment: Can you focus on a particular difficulty with that sentence? Do you understand the meaning of the sentence? Can you try to parse it yourself?

Comment: You should include the sentence that appeared before the one you've quoted, so that **that recognition** would have a clear referent.

Answer (score 1):

Let's reverse the order of the sentence and split the clauses up:

> You've cut the Palestinians off at the knees
>
> if you give Benjamin Netanyahu that <sup>(aforementioned)</sup> recognition
>
> without him having to give the Palestinians anything
>
> which is what he wants

The condition is expressed by the *if*-clause, but the condition is itself qualified by the *without*-clause.

If you recognize Netanyahu without requiring him to give the Palestinians anything in return for that recognition, you cut off the Palestinians at the knees.

> If you give Benjamin Netanyahu that <sup>(aforementioned)</sup> recognition
>
> without him having to give the Palestinians anything
>
> which is what he wants
>
> you've cut the Palestinians off at the knees

The *which*-clause, because of its placement, is ambiguous. It is not perfectly clear from the sentence whether what Netanyahu wants is simply recognition, or recognition without having to offer some *quid pro quo*.  Most people would understand the latter.

Comment: Great breakdown of this sentence! Thank you! As an English school owner, this site has proved valuable! Actually it's my first post so I plan on contributing more in the future!